# Can someone please elaborate on the difference between كرامة and سحر?

Tags: quran, sihr

What makes one permissible and the other forbidden? Under what situations? Thank you!

Comment: There's nothing in common between both. One is a gift of Allah and one is something Allah has forbidden and which is not a gift.

Comment: The question is why do you ask about this when these are two very different matters? Elaborate your post!

Comment: @Sassir I want to know what they both mean. If they have nothing to do with each other and are different matters altogether then I would appreciate if someone could explain each of their meanings. I'm not sure what else I can add to the question.